# $error tracking with AngularJs when you don't have a form and field names

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms, error-handling

Basically I have a bunch of form fields (input, textarea, select, etc.). No `<form>` and no field names per say.

eg (extract from DOM notice the classes when maxlength is exceeded):

```
<textarea placeholder="Enter a name for the new task" data-ng-model="Task.Title" data-ng-maxlength="350" class="ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-invalid ng-invalid-maxlength"></textarea>
```

Relatively straight forward in term of HTML. I want to use Angular's `ng-maxlength` to visually display an error message.

I am aware that there is something like `$scope.{form_name}.{field_name}.$error` but since I don't actually have either form and field names thus resulting in error.

`$scope.$error` - results in undefined.
`$scope.form.error` - resulted in error because of no `<from>`.
`$scope.task_title.$error` - result in error because of no `<form>`.

Should I just stick to jQuery watching for `ng-invalid` or `ng-invalid-maxlength`. Or is there still a way to track this in the controller?

Comment: `$scope.Task.Title.$error`?

Comment: @Tushar no sorry the same error ``Cannot read property '$error' of undefined`` when I try ``$scope.Task.Title.$error``. I think this is thrown because there is no ``<form>`` which automatically instantiates ``formController`` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController